# Simple example for Bilinear mapping

Tags: group-theory, functions, reference-request, examples-counterexamples, bilinear-form

Notation : $\mathbb{G}$ is an additive group and $\mathbb{G}_T$ is multiplicative group of prime order $q$.

Bilinear mapping $e: \mathbb{G} \times \mathbb{G}  \rightarrow \mathbb{G}_T$ has to satisfy two properties.

1) $e(aP,bQ) = e(P,Q)^{ab}$        for all $P,Q \in \mathbb{G} , a,b \in \mathbb{Z}_q$

2) $e(P,P) \ne 1_{\mathbb{G}_T}$ for all $P \in G$

In addition to the above two, it has to be computable.

Is there any simple example for such bilinear pairing?

I searched over internet as I can but I didn't find.

I want example like this $e(x,y) = xy \mod n$ (It's not a valid example).

Note: The sets under consideration $\mathbb{G},\mathbb{G}_T$ must have at least four elements.

Comment: Well first off your second condition is impossible since the first one implies that $e(0,0)=1$. If you accept this one tiny flaw the following is an example: $e:(\mathbb{R},+)^2 \rightarrow (\mathbb{R}_{>0},\cdot), (x,y)\mapsto \mathrm{exp}(x,y)$.

Comment: @Arthur Yeah....its $\mathbb{Z}_q$

Comment: Did you forget some condition? For me "bilinear" would imply some additivity condition in the first and second component.

Comment: I told it in notation part. @SebastianSchoennenbeck

Answer (score 0):

Take $\mathbb{G}=\mathbb{Z}_q$; take $e(1,1)$ to be any non-trivial element of $\mathbb{G}_T$, and define $e(P,Q)=e(1,1)^{PQ}$.